# Disqus comments not shown under videos on front page of site

Tags: php, disqus

i have a website.
and i am using disqus api for comments on my website. i am facing a problem. the count of comments is not shown under the video link in main page.
[in this image just views are shown but comments no shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yECxr.png)

the code i am using for this:

```
  <span class="comments"><a href="http://www.seeknfame.com/view.php?vid=<?php echo $video_id ?>#disqus_thread" ></a></span>
```

when i clicked on my video then on this page of website
http://www.seeknfame.com/view.php?vid=115  shows one comment.but in front page it shows nothing :(

and one thing more. i also include this script at the end of the page.

```
  <script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//seeknfame99.disqus.com/count.js" async></script>
```

please help me how to resolve this issue.
and one thing more. i am new here. and my english is very bad. so sorry please